# How to add instagram feed to website in 2022?

Tags: php, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I would like to show the last 8 images from my Instagram profile on my website.

I've just spent the last hour looking for info on this but can't find anything recent information anywhere. I can't believe something as simple as showing my latest posts can be so complicated!

I have custom built our site using HTML, PHP and jquery. I'm not interested in paid 3rd party software and Wordpress/Shopify plugins aren't relevant to me.

Comment: "I can't believe something as simple as showing my latest posts can be so complicated!" — Instagram do not make it easy. They want people to use their app. They don't want to host photos for display on other websites.

Comment: One way I can think of is to use selenium or other web scraping tool to get the latest embed HTML from instagram if you don't want to add it manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation if it can reassure you!

Indeed according to my research I think that Instagram have put their APIs on hold because of the Metaverse and the takeover by Facebook etc...
So it is currently impossible to display our instagram news feed on our sites, whether in PHP or JS...

It's quite compelling...